# xpath - how to select the to the contents of the file?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a file (for better readability pozwijałem other profiles and elements on which I do not care)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:4.0">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
    </extensions>

    <profiles>
        <profile name="default">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch-jberet:1.0">
            ...
        </profile>
        <profile name="ha">
        <profile name="full">
        <profile name="full-ha">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0">
                <datasources>
                    <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                        <driver>h2</driver>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>sa</user-name>
                            <password>sa</password>
                        </security>
                    </datasource>         
                    <drivers>
                        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                        </driver>
                    </drivers>
                </datasources>
            </subsystem>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</domain>
```

I would like to get to the item

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Correctness check on page http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely to be a namespace problem (search for it, or more specific keyword 'default namespace'). Basically, you need to map prefix to the default namespace URI, and use that prefix to reference element in default namespace such as the `<connection-url>` element.

Different XPath processors provide different ways to declare a namespace prefix, just search for the documentation. As for `xpathtester.com`, you can declare namespace prefix in 'Namespaces' box on the top-left area of the page in the following format (see the [documentation](http://www.xpathtester.com/help.html#namespaces)) :

```
d="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:4.0"
```

Then the following XPath succesfully return the desired text :

```
//d:connection-url/text()
```

Demo : http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/9d60daf659d2909457f218211ebec1ab